# ClickOnce Application looking in wrong directory

Tags: installation, clickonce, datadirectory

I have a program I made with an SQL database.  Everything works fine in VS 2010.  But then I publish it and it throws up an error saying it cannot find my database.  I used |DataDirectory| when I wrote the string for it so I searched for my database file.

I found a folder with my database an the application file in it.  I double clicked it and what do ya know, works fine.  My only problems is all the shortcuts that the install makes don't work, they point to an empty folder.  Is there a way to make them linked to this good folder that the installer makes?

I notice its looking for my database under a filepath under the folder name "data".  In the AppData/Local on my comp where the application is installed to there are 2 folders.  One leads to my app, the other one leads to nothing, and is labled "data."  It seems my program keeps looking in there, but like I said, if I follow the other path and run the .exe right from that folder it runs fine.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Everything is setup correctly, but the "|DataDirectory|" value points to the deployment folder, not the data folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database is part of your project, and that the build type is "content", and "copy to output" is set to "copy always". In the Application Files dialog, make sure the database shows up, and is marked Data (which it sounds like you have). Is the database included in the deployment when you publish (check the output)? IF not, is it included in the files output when you build the project?